# Is there a way to implement a commenting system such as that on medium or sitepoint in WP?

Tags: comments

Both Medium.com and SitePoint allows users to comment on individual paragraphs. I'm not sure how it's implemented but is there a way to do something similar in wordpress?

See screenshots below to see what I mean:

[image: Medium comment system]
[image: SitePoint comment system]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Medium.com but sitepoint.com use Wordpress so the answer to your question is quiet obvious: YES, there is a way to implement that in wordpress. You should make other types of questions.

I think this the implementation used by sitepoint is here: https://github.com/sitepoint/highlight-wordpress